# How is it possible to get real file's change time after updating from SVN?

Tags: file, svn, time

I have changed a CSS file, then committed it. Then updated it on another server. But the time of the updated file is time of the SVN update.

Is it possible to get the "Real" time - the one when the file change was saved on the first server?

Output of stat:

```
stat myfile.css 
  File: `myfile.css'
  Size: 29731       Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe11h/65041d    Inode: 4411064     Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: ( 1118/ valk)   Gid: ( 1010/developers)
Access: 2012-02-19 18:04:50.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2012-02-19 18:04:50.000000000 +0200
Change: 2012-02-19 18:04:50.000000000 +0200
```

Thanks

Comment: I fear that it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also configure Subversion to use **commit-times** by editing the 
Subversions config file located at  `~/.subversion/config` (UNIX, Linux) respectively 
 `%APPDATA%\subversion`(Windows)

There are these lines (around line 100 in unmodified file):

```
### Set use-commit-times to make checkout/update/switch/revert
### put last-committed timestamps on every file touched.
# use-commit-times = yes
```

Just remove the "#" from the last displayed line.

**Note** this setting is active for all your workingcopies on this machine

Comment: @valk: Be careful with this though, it may mess up your build dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Use `svn info`.  It will give you something like:

```
Path: /XXXXX/myfile.css
Name: myfile.css
URL: svn+ssh://XXXXX/current/myfile.css
Repository Root: svn+ssh://XXXXX
Repository UUID: ed4dba2c-4d18-0410-83c2-a4e2ddc248c7
Revision: 3697
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: ocharlesworth
Last Changed Rev: 3654
Last Changed Date: 2011-11-22 00:08:53 +0000 (Tue, 22 Nov 2011)
Text Last Updated: 2011-12-15 11:39:55 +0000 (Thu, 15 Dec 2011)
Checksum: 395d2b79f528cccb58017a87a76f2e50
```